# Why do my Domain systems grab a new IP when they already have one?

Tags: networking, ip, domain

We have a pool of about 250 addresses. I noticed that as the pool filled up, we started to have more and more systems that already have an IP, start to grab a new IP after reboot.
Why does this happen?
I know there are no guarantees that a system will keep it's lease but I had thought domain-joined systems would keep their IP until they were forced off of it.

Comment: What DHCP server are you using? The process of acquiring an IP address has practically nothing to do with AD domain joins.

Comment: If you are using Windows Server DHCP, most of what you see is normal. If some computers need a fixed IP for SSD some reason you can use DHCP reservation on the Server.

Comment: This all depends on the DHCP server, if it attempts to remember past IP allocations. If you have 250 computers and your local network is defined as 24-bit, the server might not have the margin to do so if its pool is almost full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use the DHCP to assign an fixed IP inside the DHCP configuration file.

Otherwise, you could try increasing the dhcp lease time, but it won't be as effective as option 1.  The lease will still expire and it may grap a new one.